# 302 Redirect on a managed Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, redirect, http-redirect

So I setup a 302 Redirect on a Godaddy's Managed Wordpress site using the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^1.2.3.4
RewriteRule .* http://example.net/we-will-be-back-soon [R=302,L]
```

I added this code onto the .htacess file of a Managed WP site Via FTP, The redirect worked perfectly but now that I am trying to get rid of it, It's not going away, The site is constantly being redirected via a 302 redirect.

I have checked the HTTP headers from multiple sources and all are saying there is a 302 redirect still in place when in actuality the redirect code is not in the .htacess file anymore.

I've also tried clearing the cache and restarting, didn't work.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay So, I gave it a few hours of breathing time and it seems the headers have updated everything seems to be working fine now.

Thank you